# How to sum a column of indeterminate size and paste the value in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Like the title says, I want to select a range of values in a certain column, H, sum them, and paste the resulting value in a cell in another sheet (same workbook.) I have the first part done:

```
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").Select
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Columns("H").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
rng1.Select
Set lastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, (8)).End(xlUp)
lastCell.Select
Set rng2 = Range(rng1, lastCell)
Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(4, 0).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count - 5, rng2.Columns.Count)
rng2.Select
```

so rng2 has all of the correct data to be summed. this is where i get stuck

Comment: so `Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A2").Value = Worksheets("Resource Plan").Evaluate("Sum(" & rng2.address(0,0) & ")")`

Comment: Loose the `.Select`'s. They are almost never necessary.  For summing, look at  `Worksheetfunction.Sum`

Comment: Hi Ron. The .Select is used for debug purposes only

Comment: Scott, that worked great, thanks. I wish I understood what it all meant!

Comment: You are basically using the worksheet function `SUM()` and assigning the value to the cell.  Lookup `Application.Evaluate` on google for many tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a `For Each` loop to go through each cell in selection then use cells row in a `Range()` assign the value to a variable and after you exit the loop assign that value to a range you want. Like so:

```
Dim cell as Range 
Dim summ as Long

summ = 0
For Each cell in Range("rng1:" & "rng2")
    summ = summ + Range("h" & cell.Row)
Next cell
Range("Your desired rng").value = summ
```